# Is micropreneur or micropreneurial correct as an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

A [micropreneur](http://www.investordictionary.com/definition/micropreneur) is basically an micro-entrepreneur.  In the following phrase, is micropreneur or micropreneurial correct?

> A micropreneur software company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Micropreneur* is a noun. 
*Micropreneurial* is the adjective form - but if i were you, I'd reconsider using that to describe a software company. I've seen it used along with nouns such as - a *micropreneurial* venture, a *micropreneurial* experience etc., 
A micropreneur is described as a person who starts a small business, so if you are trying to use this adjective to simply describe a small software business, it may work better if you just said "*micropreneurial* venture" or a *micropreneurial software business?*

Could you give out the whole sentence/context where you plan to use this phrase? Thanks. A nice question.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use *micropreneurial*, since in that context most would use *entrepreneurial*. It's more grammatically correct to use an adjective anyways; so *micropreneurial* fits the bill.

Or, you could say:

> A micropreneur's software company.